# Java floating point numbers in Octonary

Tags: java

Can be Java float point numbers literal represent in octonary?
I've read the Java [document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2) said:

> A floating-point literal may be expressed in decimal (base 10) or
>   hexadecimal (base 16).

When I try this in the IDE:

```
double d = 0b1.1D;
```

The code was highlighted as an error. but when trying:

```
double d = 011.0;            // ??
```

did not get any errors, and the output value equals to 11.0, not 9 as expected.

Does the '0' prefix just being ignored?
Appreciate any one can help.

Comment: Octonary?  You mean octal?

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to **octal**, Java does not support floating point values represented in base-8.  However, you could use `Double#doubleToLongBits` to extract the mantissa and exponent of the floating point value and convert them to an equivalent octal value.